# Ambiguous use of Subscript Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard, nsuserdefaults

I have a problem in fetching a String of a Dictionary inside NSUserdefaults, this is my code. I dont know what seem to be the problem:

```
static func getItemInUserDefaultsDictionary(key: String,dictionaryName: String) -> String {
    return defaults.objectForKey(key)![dictionaryName] as? String ?? ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does not know the proper type of `objectForKey` because it returns `AnyObject`

You have to cast the type:

```
static func getItemInUserDefaultsDictionary(key: String,dictionaryName: String) -> String {
    guard let dictionary = defaults.objectForKey(key) as? [String:AnyObject] else { return "" }
    return dictionary[dictionaryName] as? String ?? ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

static func getItemInUserDefaultsDictionary(key: String,dictionaryName: String) -> String
        {
            return (defaults.objectForKey("key")![dictionaryName] as? String)!
        }